# How to create a Dataframe with rows from two other dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to splice to dataframes together. I have a list of which rows that contain data that matches between the two dataframes.

So let's say that row 300 from dataframe 1 refers to the same company as row 2 from dataframe 2. At the moment I am creating a new dataframe with the two original ones, but it is not adding them in the right way.

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame( df1.iloc[300], df2.iloc[2]])
```

Doing this I get two rows with data from both dataframes, where what I really want is one row, with the data from both, added horizontally. So if each dataframe has 5 columns I want something that has 10 columns.

```
import pandas as pd

position_list = [(0, 85, 83),
 (1, 134, 67),
 (2, 78, 50),
 (3, 89, 83),
 (4, 90, 83),
 (5, 91, 83)]

ammended_results= Name of Applicant CMU ID  CMU Name    Capacity Awarded    Classification  Capacity (MW)   Duration (Years)    Clearing price (£)  Yearly CMU Funding (£)  Contract Length Funding (£) New Generation  Existing Generation New Capacity    Existing Capacity
1   SSE Generation Ltd. BURGH1  Burghfield  Yes Existing Generating CMU 44.034  1.0 19.4    854259.6    854259.6    0   1   0.000   44.034
2   SSE Generation Ltd. CBEU01  Deanie 1    Yes Existing Generating CMU 15.886  1.0 19.4    308188.4    308188.4    0   1   0.000   15.886
3   SSE Generation Ltd. CBEU02  Deanie 2    Yes Existing Generating CMU 15.886  1.0 19.4    308188.4    308188.4    0   1   0.000   15.886
...

ammended_register = Unique CMU Identifier   Type    Delivery Year   Name of Applicant         CM Unit Name                                            
...                           
        BURG18              T-4          2018    SSEPG (Operations) Limited  Burghfield
```

...

Basically I want to the first entry from the results dataframe with the 85th entry in the register dataframe. And create a new dataframe with all this information.

At the moment I am using this

```
df_list=[]
for i in range(len(position_list)):
    result = position_list[i][1]
    df_final = pd.concat(ammended_results.iloc[i], ammended_register.iloc[results]])
    df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    df_list.append(df)
```

fr = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0)

but the final dataframe I am getting is not adding them in the right way

Comment: Post a [MCVE], please. I *think* you just want `pd.concat`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I have added those now

Answer (score 2):

easy peasy lemon squeezy

```
pd.concat([ df1.iloc[300], df2.iloc[2]], axis = 1)
```

Comment: I should have got that 